# How was the first programming language written?

Tags: history

There is a need of a programming language to even accept a language. So where was it written at first ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages

Comment: I recall having to write instructions in binary back at the uni.

Comment: I agree that it was binary codes. But in which computer was it written ?

Answer (score 5):

[Compiler bootstrapping.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) The very first compiler (assembler) was implemented in pure hardware or machine code.

Comment: can i know more about it please ?

Comment: @user2141542 More what? I don't think I could make up a complete lecture on this within the boundaries of a Stack Overflow-answer.